# Restricting access to custom domains in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to restrict user access to view the custom domains added to Azure AD please? I have tried to create a custom role in Azure RBAC with scope of "/" but this is not permitted.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** you cannot restrict user to view specific custom domain at azure active directory at this moment. Azure active directory does not have this feature.

You can use an [allow list or a deny list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/allow-deny-list) to allow or block invitations to users from specific organizations. You could take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/allow-deny-list)

You also can [restrict your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users) over your resource group and user.

> **Note:** To know more about the scope  the RBAC you could refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal)